# For $V$ vector space, $W$ subspace, $V \simeq W \oplus V/W$?

Tags: vector-spaces, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I thought this seemed intuitively true. So I searched for it but never found it. I thought that if it were true, surely it would appear somewhere in the Rank-Nullity Theorem page on Wikipedia. But no luck. So I tried to prove it and I think I have done. But I'm obviously very sceptical about my own work here. Is this correct ?

Let $V$ be a vector space over some field $K$ and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. 
Then $V/W$ is a vector space over $K$, so  it has a basis $\mathcal B$. Define a linear map $ \phi : V/W \rightarrow V$ by choosing $\phi(x)$ for any $x \in \mathcal B$. More precisely, do it such that $\phi(x) \in x \quad \forall x \in \mathcal B$, in which case this property extends to all $x \in V/W$

For variables in $V$ I shall use $v$ instead of $x$ to avoid confusion. Let $p$ be the projection onto $V/W$. 
My claim is that $f : \begin{array}{cccc} V & \rightarrow & W \oplus V/W \\ v & \mapsto & (v-\phi \circ p (v),\, p(v)) \end{array}$ is an isomorphism.

As an ordered pair of sums and compositions of linear maps, $f$ is linear.

Let's prove that $f$ is injective. $f(v) = 0 \iff (\,p(v)=0 \,\text{and}\, v- \phi \circ p(v)=0\,) \implies v-\phi(0)=0 \implies v=0$

$f$ is onto since for any $(\alpha,\, y) \in  W \oplus V/W$ we have $f(\alpha + \phi(y))=(\alpha+\phi(y)-\phi \circ p (\alpha + \phi(y)),\,  p (\alpha + \phi(y))\,)$ 
On the right hand side of the ordered pair, $p(\alpha)=0$ since $\alpha \in W$, and also $p(\phi(y))=y$ as $\phi(y)\in y \in V/W$ so in total we're left with $y$. 
As for the left hand side, we $\alpha + \phi(y) - \phi(\text{the right hand side})$ which adds up to $\alpha$, QED.

Comment: This is correct, but notice that in general there is no such isomorphism that is *natural*; the construction here depends on the (arbitrary) choice of splitting map $\phi : V / W \to V$.

Comment: Of course, I totally agree.

Comment: You're likelier to find this result stated/discussed in fancier language, e.g., "Every short exact sequence of vector spaces splits".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true, irrespective of $V$ being finitely generated or not, but it relies on the axiom of choice, that's used to prove every subspace has a complement.

If you accept the existence of a complement (which usually people do), then you have a projection along it and you get the result. Namely, if $W'$ is a subspace so that $W\cap W'=\{0\}$ and $W+W'=V$, you can define $p\colon V\to W$ by $p(v)\in W$ and $v-p(v)\in W'$. Observe $p$ is linear.

Then you can define $g\colon V\to W'$ with $g(v)=v-p(v)$; this map is surjective and has kernel $W$, so it induces an isomorphism $q\colon V/W\to W'$.

Then define $f\colon V\to W\oplus V/W$ by
$$
f(v)=\bigl(p(v),q^{-1}(v-p(v))\bigr)
$$
and prove it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space over field $K$ and $W$ be a $K$-sub space of $V$.

Now let us consider the natural surjective map $\eta : V \rightarrow V/W$, where  $\eta (x) = x + W$.

Note that,  ker $\eta = W$.

Let $\{ x_{i} + W \}_{i \in I}$ be a $K$-basis of $V/W$.

Now let $y_{i} \in V$ such that $\eta(y_{i}) = x_{i} +W$ for all $i \in I$.

Note that $y_{i}$'s are linearly independent and let $W'$ be the subspace spanned by $y_{i}$'s.

Extend the set of linearly independent vectors $A = \{ y_{i} \}_{i \in I}$ to a basis set $B$ of $V$.

Note that $B \setminus A$ is a basis set of $W$.

So, $V = W \oplus W'$.

And $W' \cong V/W$ implies that $V \cong W \oplus V/W$.

Answer (score 0):

Vector spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension.

Comment: Of course... so my statement is correct ! I'm surprised I couldn't find it anywhere though, cause it actually gives more information than its "dimensional" version.

Comment: @JamesWell Note that your proof is quite a bit more complicated than it has to be. Just chose a basis for $V$ and $W\oplus V/W$, and chose any bijection between the bases to get an isomorphism

Comment: Actually, about your answer, does it still hold for infinite dimensional vector spaces ? What if one vector space has a non-countable basis and the other one has a countable one ?

Comment: @JamesWell It is true in the infinite dimensional case as well. If one has uncountable dimension and the other has countable dimension, then their dimensions aren't equal, and so they aren't isomorphic

Comment: I must be making some mistake then, because : uncoutable sets $A$ and $B$ don't necessarily have the same cardinality. Then there is no one-to-one correspondence between a basis of $\oplus_AK$ and one of $\oplus_BK$ inducing and isomorphism is there ?

Comment: @JamesWell The dimension of a vector space is the cardinality of a basis. If two vector spaces have two different uncountable dimensions, then as you said there is no bijection between the bases, and hence the two vector spaces are not isomorphic